# HTML how to make horizontal bar tabs center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a horizontal bar here. And I was wondering. How do I make tabs on the bar center. And not to the left. Could someone please tell me how to do this? Also include a snippet for me please?

My code:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;

}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Adding display: flex and justify-content: center to the UI element should do it

Comment: Great glad it is working for you. Just be advised if you need to support old browsers that it may not work or you may have to prefix you css.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center;` on the `UL` element and than set `display: inline-block;` on your `LI` elements ( instead of floating)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;     /* add */
}

li {
  /*float: left;*/ display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block; 
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `float:left` to `display:inline-block` and give `text-align:center` to ul class.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align:center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

add **text-align:center;** **of ul** and change **display:inline-block;** **of li**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align : center;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Ans may be it is helpful to you. now text is center;

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align:center;
}

li {
 float: none; 
   
  display:inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

<del>You could set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto on the UL element (or any wrapper you might have).</del>

`margin-auto` works for elements with a width that is less than the page width, in this case the `ul` is taking the entire width so there is nothing to center, `text-align: center` for the `ul` and `display: inline-block` are the solution in this case.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
</ul>
```